# proper way to use QFile::write?

Tags: c++, qt5

I need write `n` bytes to file and I have `QTemporaryFile`,
how should I write these bytes?

I read `QIODevice::write` documentation:

> qint64 QIODevice::write(const char *data, qint64 maxSize) Writes at
>   most maxSize bytes of data from data to the device. Returns the number
>   of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.

so looks like I need cycle to write bytes, because of there is no grantee
that it writes all bytes, it may return control after writting `k` bytes,
where `k` < `n`.

I can create `QDataStream` from `TemporaryFile`, but `QDataStream::writeRawData` function has the same restriction:

> int QDataStream::writeRawData(const char *s, int len) Writes len bytes
>   from s to the stream. Returns the number of bytes actually written, or
>   -1 on error. The data is not encoded.

so there is no function in `Qt` that write exactly `n` bytes or return error?

Comment: `so there is no function in Qt that write exactly n bytes or return error` well, that exactly what `QIODevice::write` do with error condition as `k != n`

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov but documentation says that on error it returns `-1`, about `k` <= `n`, there is no mention that on error it returns `k >= 0` and `k != n`, so may be in some cases it is normal

Comment: my bad, didn't read the doc properly. Then, condition is `k == -1 || k != n` where `k` is return value of `write`. There's no need of such a simple function in a library when you can write a wrapper yourself :)

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov, `k == -1 || k != n` is exactly the same thing as `k != n` for k≥0. Still, this in no way answers to the user1244932's question: per documentation, `write` can return values in range {0, 1, …, n-1} in perfectly successful cases (e.g. “for optimization reasons, only a part was written, please call `write` again if you want to write everything”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a weird thing…

On the one hand:

- `QFile::write`'s implementation is based on `writeData`, and [documentation for the `QIODevice::writeData` abstract method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#writeData) says:

  > When reimplementing this function it is important that this function writes all the data available before returning. [The next few sentences, as far as I understand them, tell that that's important, because the relying class `QDataStream` in its high-level methods (which don't return a number of bytes written) don't do the cycling.]

  So, it seems that we don't need to do the cycling either.
- Really, `QFileDevice::writeData` (which overrides `QIODevice::writeData`) seems to call the `QFSFileEnginePrivate::writeFdFh` method (specifically: `QIODevice::write` → `QFileDevice::writeData` → `QFSFileEngine::write` → `QFSFileEnginePrivate::nativeWrite` → `QFSFileEnginePrivate::writeFdFh`), which [does the cycling by itself](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfsfileengine.cpp.html#_ZN20QFSFileEnginePrivate9writeFdFhEPKcx):

  ```
  if (fh) {
      // Buffered stdlib mode.
      size_t result;
      do {
          result = fwrite(data + writtenBytes, 1, size_t(len - writtenBytes), fh);
          writtenBytes += result;
      } while (result == 0 ? errno == EINTR : writtenBytes < len);
  } else if (fd != -1) {
      // Unbuffered stdio mode.
      SignedIOType result;
      do {
          // calculate the chunk size
          // on Windows or 32-bit no-largefile Unix, we'll need to read in chunks
          // we limit to the size of the signed type, otherwise we could get a negative number as a result
          quint64 wantedBytes = quint64(len) - quint64(writtenBytes);
          UnsignedIOType chunkSize = std::numeric_limits<SignedIOType>::max();
          if (chunkSize > wantedBytes)
              chunkSize = wantedBytes;
          result = QT_WRITE(fd, data + writtenBytes, chunkSize);
      } while (result > 0 && (writtenBytes += result) < len);
  ```
- And the higher-level methods in Qt, like the ones in `QTextStream` and `QDataStream` (e.g. see [`QTextStream::operator<<(const QString &string)` and the underlying methods](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/serialization/qtextstream.cpp.html#_ZN11QTextStreamlsERK7QString), [`QDataStream::operator<<(const char *s)` and the underlying methods](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/serialization/qdatastream.cpp.html#_ZN11QDataStreamlsEPKc)), don't do the cycling for their own (relying on the cycling in the `QFSFileEnginePrivate::writeFdFh` instead).

So, it looks like Qt doesn't follow the typical POSIX conventions a-la “reading/writing less than requested isn't necessarily an error, just retry”. Instead `QFile`'s methods are tuned to read/write less than requested only in the case of error. So normally you shouldn't do the cycling around `QFile::write` yourself.

But, on the other hand, according to a thread “QFile::write(const QByteArray&) does not write all data?” in the “Interest” Qt mailing list for [May 2018](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2018-May/thread.html), there exist cases when `QFile::write` writes less than requested and the cycling around `QFile::write` is useful. At least they existed in May 2018, [Alexander Golks said he couldn't reproduce the problem after upgrading to Qt 5.6.4](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2018-May/030063.html) (but I have no idea what exactly was fixed/changed, as the cycling was `QFSFileEnginePrivate::writeFdFh` for many years before that). But the main shock for me is not that the `QFile::write` without outer cycling wasn't sufficient in one of older Qt versions (who knows, maybe it was a fixed-now Qt bug or an hardware/driver problem which had to be solved by other means) but that the mailing list members who take direct participation in the Qt development (e.g. Thiago Macieira) stayed on the position that a-la “don't expect `QFile::write` to write everything, do the cycling”.

**Conclusion**. I don't know what to say. My guess is that:

- The *spirit* of Qt is “`QIODevice::write` will write less than requested only in the case of error, therefore external cycling isn't required”. That's why the Qt developers neither provided convenient methods for external cycling around `QIODevice::write` nor do the external cycling around `QIODevice::write` themselves in higher-level classes like `QTextStream`, `QDataStream`.
- However they didn't dare to promise that such approach will work (always and for all `QIODevice` descendants). That's why the *letter* of documentation doesn't give such guarantees. (It only applies *obligations to `QIODevice::writeData` implementers* but not *privileges to `QIODevice::write` users*.)
- My personal choice is not to do the external cycling around `QFile::write`.

Answer (score -1):

How do you propose *undoing* the write of some bytes, in the case where there is no error but fewer than `n` bytes were written? Especially if there is data already in the file (either previous `writes` that succeeded, or because you are appending).

It is also likely that any further attempts to write to a file that didn't write all `n` bytes will also fail or write 0, without outside action. The circumstance that springs to mind is exhaustion of free disk space.

Comment: Some misunderstanding has come about, I suppose. I am afraid about what exactly you describe, disk out of space and I don't receive `-1` and do `QFile::write` again and again. But I am also afraid  if Qt on some platforms uses async I/O for files, and so return `k`, `k < n` is normal situation, like for sockets it is completely ok. So I return error when `k < n`, but actually all ok, and I just have to call `QFile::write` again instead of report error to user.

Comment: "uses async I/O for files, and so return k, k < n is normal situation," Have you *observed* that? the *implementation* using an asynchronous mechanism, and then waiting for it to finish, is still syncronous

Comment: I do not observe anything. I make my judgment based only on documentation, because of I write multi-platform code and have no ability to test on all platforms at the current moment. Documentation distinguish partly writes and errors. So I suppose it may use async I/O for files also, and there is no hint in documentation about synchronous behavior for files. So I am interesting in the right way to write exactly `n` bytes or fire error. You suggest make assumption that if `k != n` this is also error, for any `n > 0`, but I can not find any proof about this in Qt documentation.

Comment: No, I am saying that you are allowed to have a definition of error that doesn't precisely match the Qt definition. You want a binary "Success or Failure" measure. Qt provides a ternary "Success, Partial Success or Failure" measure. That necessarily implies mapping two states onto one. *How* you define that mapping is totally up to you.